# multiprocessing python pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, selenium, pymongo

I'm trying to do the following: grab some information off a page, and then insert it into a mongodb. There are a list of pages and I'm wanting to multiprocessing as these pages can take time to load. Once the webdriver returns the result I want to insert into the db. The problem I'm facing is that I'm only getting 1/4 of the results I'm expecting in the db, so I imagine the way I'm managing the results and the inserting isn't working. I was hoping someone could show me where I've gone wrong. The following is an example of the code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from selenium import webdriver
import timeit
from pymongo import MongoClient
def mp_worker(urls):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,
            chrome_options=options)
    url = "http://website"+urls
    driver.get(url)

    return what_you_want

    driver.quit() #do I do this here, close or quit?

def mp_handler():
    urls= ["14360705","4584061","13788961","6877217","13194596","13400479","9868014","8524704","16394198","16315464"]
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.test
    collection = db['test-collection']

    p = Pool(cpu_count()*2)
    for result in p.imap(mp_worker, urls):  
        db.restaurants.update(result,{"upsert":"True"})

if __name__=='__main__':
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    mp_handler()
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print (stop - start)
```

Comment: Have you checked that all the pages that you are scraping return data? May be only 1/4 of them actually do return anything.

Comment: yes if i scrape it going sequentially with a for loop I get the full results

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is incorrect:

```
db.restaurants.update(result,{"upsert":"True"})
```

You want, likely:

```
db.restaurants.insert(result)
```

Or:

```
db.restaurants.update(filter, result, upsert=True)
```

Where "filter" is a MongoDB query (expressed as a Python dict) that uniquely matches the document you want to update or create.